# What can be said about the sum $f(x) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} e^{-x\sqrt{m}}\cos(x\sqrt{m})$ for $x>0$?

Tags: summation, exponential-sum

I recently ran into the function $f(x)$ defined by the sum
$$
f(x) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} e^{-x\sqrt{m}}\cos(x\sqrt{m})\, 
$$
where $x>0$, and I've been unable to make head or tails of it either numerically or analytically.

I've tried a number of things to no avail. The Poisson summation formula fails because the Fourier transform of the summand is more intractable than what we started with. The Euler Maclaurin formula does not apply since the quantity $e^{-x\sqrt{m}}\cos(x\sqrt{m})$ is not differentiable in $m$ at $m = 0$.

Due to its relatively slow convergence, this sum is also hard to evaluate numerically for various values of $x$. All I can say is that numerically it looks like
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0_+} f(x) = -1/2\, ,
$$
but I haven't been able to prove this.

What can be proven about this sum? Does it have a closed form? (I doubt it.) Is there a way to characterize the behavior for small $x$? Is there a more efficient way to evaluate it numerically? Is there some way to approximate it?

Comment: Write the sum as $e^{-x}\cos(x)+\sum_{n=2}^\infty e^{-sqrt{n}\,x}\cos(\sqrt{n}\,x)$.  Now, use the Euler-Maclaurin Summation Formula.

Comment: Just curious ... Why do you believe that this series converges slowly.  The exponential term decays very rapidly, even with $-\sqrt{n} \,x$ as its argument.

Comment: @Dr.MV Well, to be honest, I had inferred slow convergence from Mathematica's difficulty in evaluating this sum numerically. It may be that when $x$ is not small, it does converge rapidly. When $x$ is small, however, this sum does indeed seem to pose difficulties.

Comment: As $x\to 0$, the series diverges.  Fix $x>0$ and increase the number of terms in the truncated series.

Comment: @Dr.MV At $x=0$ the series clearly diverges. But is it necessarily clear that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0_+}f(x) = f(0)$?

Comment: Note that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\,dy\, e^{-x\sqrt{y}}\cos(x\sqrt{y}) = 0$ for all $x>0$.

Comment: Note that $$\int_1^\infty e^{-x\,\sqrt{y}}\cos(x\sqrt{y})\,dy=\frac{e^{-x}((x+1)\sin(x)-x\cos(x))}{x^2}$$It is unclear that the EMSF provides a useful asymptotic expansion of the truncated series.  The "constant term" is actually a function of $x$, which is not trivial to estimate from the EMSF.

Comment: @Dr.MV Actually, upon fiddling with it further, it looks like you were right in your original comment: The EMSF works fine when starting the sum at 2 instead of 1, and it yields the conjectured limit $f(0_+) = -1/2$.